# programmatically loaded iframe ignoring margins

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following code that loads some html in an iframe when a "view" is loaded.

```
var clientPage = xx.Repository.getClientPage("CustomPage-" + this._pageId);         
var iframe = window.frames["clientPage"].document; 

iframe.open();
//iframe.write(clientPage.pageHtml);
iframe.close();

$("body", iframe).append(clientPage.pageHtml);
```

and the following html:

```
   <!-- Client Page --> 
   <div id="client_page" class="ui_page" style="display: block;">
        <div id="clientPageInnerContent">
           <iframe id="clientPage" ></iframe>
        </div>
   </div>
```

The code works and the iframe renders correctly but the iframe is disregarding a margin defined in css class ui_page.

I have tried adding a delay, loading the html in a different way and programmatically adding a margin but nothing seems to work. 
If I open the chrome dev tools and toggle the margin off and on the iframe moves into the correct position. But I have not been able to do that through code.

How can I define a margin that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by placing the iframe in the Div and used a fixed position on the div.